# How works (and using) RESTful's caching

Tags: php, rest

I developed a really small REST API (using PHP), which provides information about users (also update and create users but it doesn't matter for the question). just to show the available calls (JSON output, by the way):

`/api/users/54216`

`/api/users/54216?fields=id,name`

`/api/users/54216/photos`

`54216` is an example user id.

Until this day, I used caching only to save html pages to display, really not complicated - never used cache to save only data.

What should I do to save these calls, and how do I use it then? My target is (I think..) to save the data to `JSON` file one time at X minutes and when needed, get the file cache and `decode` it.

In addition, how do you recommend me to cache specific the information of user? because call no.1 output all the information and call no.2 output only specific fields, I don't wanna use 2 cache files because it's really not effective.

I have never taken a part in this section (cache [json] data & REST API, it's my first time), so I am very confused.

**EDIT:**

I am talking about server-side caching.

Comment: I'm confused do you want to cache the files client side or server side. Generally caching is completely used for performance reasons. If this is a really simple JSON object just save important data to cookies. If you are trying to cache JSON server side for 5 minutes what do you expect to gain by caching i.e. is the same user making the same call? JSON is so light weight that I think you are over thinking this and caching is probably not necessary, but I'll help you out if I can.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I'm talking about server side caching. The output is used to display, for example, user's profile (but REALLY not only), so the meaning at this example is that a person in the website can watch several users (It's not each one for himself, so cookies do not help this situation). I get the content of the JSON document with PHP (using cURL) and sometimes with JavaScript.

Comment: I forgot to say: several persons can make the same call, of course. If I continue to talk about the the previous example with the profile - for example, 10 persons can watch the same user profile, so actually they make the same call. Caching is absolutely needed here (and in addition I want to know how to do it :-)). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read [HTTP Cache](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html)

> The first important principal is to understand how HTTP Caching Works,
>   there are basically two parts, TTL (Cache-Control) and Stale Check
>   (ETag). When a resource is generated by an origin server you need to
>   think of it is gone.  You no longer have control over it, you only get
>   to make suggestions to the client what to do with it.  The two
>   mechanism you have are TTL (which is how long the client should keep
>   the object in cache before checking back) and Stale Check (which is a
>   version of the resource that was returned) that can be sent with a new
>   GET request to the origin server, to say "Hey I have this version is
>   it still good".  Giving the Origin server the opportunity to say yep,
>   keeping using that one and provide a new TTL, if it is still valid.
>
> You need to use these two controls in different ways to get the
>   effects you want.  For instance when serving files that will never
>   change (like the css for a build)  you can set a really long TTL, and
>   no etag.  For something that doesn't change very often, but when it
>   does change needs to be quick (like the party members on a
>   reservation) you would set a low TTL (like 1 minute) and an ETag. In
>   this second example you set a low TTL of 1 minute to help with bursts
>   from clients to not overwhelem the origin server (scale) and the ETag
>   allows the Origin server to skip the construction of the reservation
>   object, if it has a way to verify what the current valid ETag is
>   faster than constructing the entire reservation.  Another example
>   would be something that doesn't change often and when it does, it can
>   propagate slowly (like a user's ad recommendation profile)  You can
>   set a higher TTL (like 6 hours) and not worry so much about an ETag
>   (although it would still be useful).
>   REf: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/api-craft/YJMH0XMQJIM/HtdAPEXbQLMJ

Or, if you want to cache on server side, have a look at memcached ([tutorial](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/25/10-baby-steps-to-install-memcached-server-and-access-it-with-php/))

And also look at Reverse Proxy cache solutions like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-network-caching-http-headers

This explains Caching from iOS perspective, but the term Cache-Control, max-age, ETags, Last Modified are explained well.